# Why are sigma-algebras defined to include the ambient set?

Tags: real-analysis

For example, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra) (among many texts) defines a sigma algebra $\Sigma \subset 2^X$ of some set $X$ such that

1. $X \in \Sigma$,
2. If $A \in \Sigma$ then $A^c \in \Sigma$, and
3. If $\{A_j\}_{j=1}^\infty \subset \Sigma$ then $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j \in \Sigma$.

Why is $X \in \Sigma$ explicitly necessary, as it seems redundant given the other two conditions?  Indeed, let $A \in \Sigma$.  Then $A^c \in \Sigma$ by 2, and so $A \cup A^c = X \in \Sigma$ by 3.

Comment: What if $\Sigma = \emptyset $?

Comment: @ArthurFischer Ah, okay.  I suppose if we define $\Sigma$ to be nonempty from the beginning, though, the above would hold?

Comment: Yes, requiring non-emptiness is equivalent in the presence of the other conditions.

Comment: In the following link http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sigma-Algebra.html they assume that $\Sigma\neq\emptyset$, but the definition of $\sigma-$ algebra still belongs to the above three condition. Why?

Comment: @ksantas: Why not? It is not necessary, but it is not wrong either. Definitions (especially on random websites) are not always trying to be absolutely non-redundant.